# Past and date comparison condition

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

With the below code, I'm unable to set the following:

1. Start date should be of future
2. End date should be higher than start date

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="maintsd">Maintenance Start Date (<%=tzShort%>)</label></td>
    <td><input style="border:1px solid grey; width: 100%" type="datetime-local" id="maintsd" required="true" name="maintsd"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="mainted">Maintenance End Date (<%=tzShort%>)</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  style="border:1px solid grey; width: 100%"  type="datetime-local" id="mainted" required="true" name="mainted">
    </td>
```

Date is in T format.

Date which is being saved is retrieved as below:

```
 public String getMaintEDString() {
  //  ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(this.maintED, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    this.maintEDString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").format(datetime);
    return maintEDString;
}

public String getMaintSDString() {
  //   ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
    LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(this.maintSD, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    this.maintSDString = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").format(datetime);
    return maintSDString;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSP validation with java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537679/jsp-validation-with-java-class)

Comment: What exactly you need to do ? with jsp are you are able to display date in input ? what doesn't work?

Comment: Hello,
The input should have the constraint. Like the past date should not be 'selectable' and while submit the end date should be greater than start date as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` attribute in your input-box and set there min-date this will disable all previous date i.e : `min="<%=tzShort%>"` and then on click of submit button get both inputs i.e : start and end date compare both values and depending on this show error message or submit form.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function validate() {
  //get start and end date and convert to dates 
  var sdate = new Date(document.getElementById("maintsd").value);
  var edate = new Date(document.getElementById("mainted").value);
  var flag = true; //for validating
  //if end date is greater
  if (edate >= sdate) {
    console.log("end_date is greater then strt_date");
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    flag = false;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*end_date should be  greater then strt_date"; //show this message

  }
  return flag;
}
```

```html
<!--onsubmit validate will get called-->
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="maintsd">Maintenance Start Date (<%=tzShort%>)</label></td>
      <td><input style="border:1px solid grey; width: 100%" type="datetime-local" id="maintsd" required="true" name="maintsd" value="2020-08-12T10:22" min="2020-08-12T10:22"></td>
      <!-- add min date so backdates with be disable-->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="mainted">Maintenance End Date (<%=tzShort%>)</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input style="border:1px solid grey; width: 100%" type="datetime-local" id="mainted" required="true" name="mainted" value="2020-08-19T10:22" min="2020-08-12T10:22">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="error" style="color:red"></p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```